# Connected component

Tags: general-topology

please how to prove that the connected components form a partition of the topological space ?

I know that they are closed and disjoint but how to conclude?

Thank you

Comment: "I know that they are closed and disjoint but how to conclude?". If you focus on DISJOINT you are done, if you know that any element is in one connected component

Comment: @Enkidu the connected compenent exists always ?

Comment: well, you already know that all connected components are disjoint, hence their union is a disjoint union, so you just need to conclude that the union of all connected components is the whole space. i.e. you need to prove that any point lies in one connected component

Answer (score 0):

There is a relation $\sim$ on the elements of the topological space $X$ prescribed by:$$x\sim y\iff\text{ a connected set }C\subseteq X\text{ exists  with }x,y\in C$$
This relation can be shown to be an equivalence relation, so induces a partition on $X$.

Also it can be shown that the equivalence classes are the components of $X$.

So with that you are ready.

If $[x]$ denotes the equivalence class represented by $x$ then $[x]$ can be shown to be the union of all connected subsets of $X$ that contain $x$ as element, and can be recognized as the component that has $x$ has element.

Comment: here you take $x\in X$ and you prove that there exists a connected compenent which contines x?

Comment: @PolineSandra The set $\{x\}$ is connected so the collection of connected sets that contain $x$ as element is not empty. Then let $C$ denote the union of these sets. Because the sets have a point in common it can be shown that this union is connected as well, and this union is actually the connected component that contains $x$.